# MvvmCross Xamarin.Forms MasterDetail Back + Master Menu Button at the same time?

Tags: xamarin.forms, mvvmcross

Is it somehow possible to have the Back button in the NavigationBar and also the Master (Hamburger) menu icon with MvvmCross for Xamarin.Forms? Like the Amazon app does it on iOS.